# didBeginContact not called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision

I am making a game in which I need my spriteNodes to collide. I followed a tutorial but it just isn't working for me.

When I run my game and two objects collide, there is no println("beginContact") in the output monitor, so the didBeginContact function isn't called.

```
override init(size:CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    player.planeSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane5")

    player.planeSprite.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.planeSprite.size)
    player.planeSprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = true;
    player.planeSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    player.planeSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = noteCategory;
    player.planeSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0;
    player.planeSprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;

    player.planeSprite.position = CGPointMake(player.legalPositions[1], player.planeSprite.size.height/2)

    self.addChild(player.planeSprite)
}

func addNote() {
    var note:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "note")
    note.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: note.size)
    note.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    note.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = noteCategory
    note.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
    note.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    let minX = note.size.width/2
    let maxX = self.frame.size.width - note.size.width/2
    let rangeX = maxX - minX
    let position = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

    note.position = CGPointMake(player.legalPositions[position], self.frame.size.height + note.size.height)

    self.addChild(note)
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
    println("beginContact")

    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & noteCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0 ) {
        println("if statement")
        playerDidCollideWithNote(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, note: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }
}

func playerDidCollideWithNote(plane:SKSpriteNode, note:SKSpriteNode) {
    println("hit")
    note.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Usually issues where functions are not called is because the .delegate property is not set.

Comment: yup you need to set the scene as the physics world delegate

Comment: Do you mean like this: class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

Comment: Yes, and add "self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self" to your didMoveToView method.

Comment: I did that and it still wont work

Comment: How have you set the bitmask values?

Comment: I've done it like this: 
let noteCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let playerCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs,

> An object that implements the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol can respond when two physics bodies with overlapping
>   contactTestBitMask values are in contact with each other in a physics
>   world. To receive contact messages, you set the contactDelegate
>   property of a SKPhysicsWorld object. The delegate is called when a
>   contact starts or ends.

Consequently, you'll need to adopt the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol and set the `physicsWorld`'s `contactDelegate` property to the SKScene by

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Also, you should remove the ? from the following statements

```
player.planeSprite.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.planeSprite.size)

note.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: note.size)
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use Xcode8.0 Swift3.0, You cannot use
`func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {}`

So you should use this.
`func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {}`

Comment: Pain in my butt, that did it! I converted from older swift to 3.0 and could not figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Such a saviour! Thank you @Rasukaru

Comment: This happened to me only when migrating from Swift3 to Swift4 and then to Swift5. Otherwise, it was working fine with didBeginContact

Answer (score 12):

Done this misstake several times.

You first need to inherit from SKPhysicsContactDelegate :

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate { ... }
```

And then in your didMoveToView method, add:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}
```

To set your GameScene instance as the contactDelegate for the physicsWorld.

Comment: NICE ONE!! :) - Just a quick question when would you use assign this to another object?